# Odds of drawing all seven doubles in a set of dominoes

Tags: probability

One night, when I was a child, my father stirred our set of dominoes face down and asked me to pick a double. I pulled one double after another out of the set, seven in total. I've always wondered what the odds were of doing that. It was a 28-tile set.

Comment: "I pulled one double after another" How? Did the dominoes have their dotted sides up and were you able to see them?

Comment: No, they were face down, which is why I remember it, 50+ years later.

Comment: It wasn't clear from your original post that you picked the dominos at random.  I'm voting to reopen your question.

Comment: Really, all these close votes? What an excellent question!